# Validação do update no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, validação, crud

Eu estou com um problema para fazer validação no update no Laravel.

Meu Controller esta assim:

```
public function editar(EspecieRequest $request, Especie $esp)
{
    $especie = Especie::find($esp->id_especie);
    $valores = Request::all();
    $especie->fill($valores)->save();

    return redirect()->action('EspecieController@lista');
}
```

Meu Request esta assim:

```
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'nome_especie.required' => 'O campo nome é necessário'. $this->id_especie,
...
        ];
    }
```

O erro que o laravel mostra é esse:
"Call to a member function fill() on null"

Comment: De um `var_dump($esp);`, pode ser que `$esp` esteja sem valor, ou a variável `$valores` esteja recebendo nulo.

Comment: tem que verificar `$especie` se retornou algum dado

Comment: `function editar(EspecieRequest $request, Especie $esp)` isso que ta estranho ...!

Comment: O $esp não tinha eu fiz no tentativa e erro, eu fiz o var_dump de $esp e $valores e travou o meu pc, depois eu fiz de uma variável só, não me lembro qual e vi que saiu um lixo de memória nela

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro é causado quando você usa a função `find` e a mesma não encontra nenhum resultado correspondente no banco de dados para o `ID` do `Model` pesquisado.

Em tais casos, eu costumo usar `findOrFail` para evitar esse tipo de problema.

Exemplo:

```
 $especie = Especie::findOrFail($request->id_especie);
```

Caso o resultado para `id_especie` não seja encontrado no banco, uma exceção chamada `ModelNotFoundException` será lançada.

Inclusive é uma boa forma, por sinal, de se evitar que o seu código continue sendo executado de maneira inesperada caso o resultado não seja retornado.

No seu código há algo que parece não fazer muito  sentido: Você está recebendo o `Especie $esp` como parâmetro, mas está buscando ele novamente no banco de dados através de outra consulta?

Se você estiver fazendo bind do objeto `Especie` através das rotas, talvez você precise alterar o seu código apenas para isso:

```
public function editar(EspecieRequest $request, Especie $esp)
{

    $valores = $request->all();

    $esp->fill($valores)->save();

    return redirect()->action('EspecieController@lista');
}
```

Comment: O meu método original não tinha Especie $esp, fiz na tentativa e erro, o problema é que quando ele passa no request, o request não me volta os valores para update

Comment: @lipesmile, você deu um `dd($request::all())`, pra saber se os dados estão chegado? Caso não der certo, o que acho difícil, mudar o parâmetro da função para `Request $request` para ter certeza que você está mandando caso ainda persista o problema ai o erro provavelmente é como você está mandando...

Comment: Não deveria ser `$request::all()` em vez de `Request:all()`, já que `$request` é o que está vindo do parâmetro?

Comment: Bem notado @RicardoLucas